# Measurement, lognormal distribution, Monte-Carlo

Tags: probability-distributions, monte-carlo

I do have problems to understand the lognormal distribution.
So, I do have one measurement M, measured with a sensor having a std S.
As the sensor is not too accurate I want to build up a list of values which might also be true due to the std of the sensor.
As my measurement can't be negative I need a lognormal distribution.
As far as I understood it, I want a lognormal distribution with mean M and std S.
How do I reach that?
Taking samples via X(theta_i) = exp(M + S * theta_i); theta being a normal distributed random number (matlab 'rndn'), i = 1...10e6 doesn't give a distribution with mean M.

Comment: Lognormal is a relative to the normal distribution, but you need to do a logarithm in one place. Also does rndn even exist in matlab? Do you mean rand or randn?

Comment: randn does exist in matlab, yes.  But don't I need a distribution which is a relative to the normal distribution? Because in general the measurement values should be normal distributed, they just can't take any negative values. 
Or is my assumption wrong and my distribution in the end does not need to have the mean of my prior measurement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $X \sim Log \mathcal N (\mu, \sigma^2)$ we have $\mathbb E[X]=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$, meaning that the mean of such a variable is not $\mu$ (similarly with the variance). Refer to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for more information on the log-normal distribution.

If you want the standard deviation of $X$ to be $S$ and the mean to be $M$ (not the parameters of the distribution) then you have to solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ the following  system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
M = \mathbb E[X] = e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}, \\
S^2 = \mathbb V[X] = (e^{\sigma^2} - 1) e^{2\mu + \sigma^2}.
\end{cases}
$$

By noting that $e^{2\mu + \sigma^2} = (e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2})^2 = M^2$, we get from the second equation $(S/M)^2 = e^{\sigma^2} - 1$, which gives us

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\ln{\left(\left(\frac{S}{M}\right)^2 + 1\right)}}
$$

which is defined where the argument of the square root "makes sense". Placing $\sigma$ into the first equation we get

$$
e^\mu =M e^{-\sigma^2} = M e^{-\ln{\left(\left(\frac{S}{M}\right)^2 + 1\right)}} = M \frac{M^2}{S^2}.
$$

Thus we get $\mu = \ln{M^3/S^2}$. Since $X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z}$ with $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, we can use the previously computed $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to simulate samples from a log-normal distribution with desired parameters.